# How to create a new element in visualcomposer.io API ( visual composer) (not a wpbakery)

Tags: json, wordpress, visual-composer

How to explore this API https://visualcomposer.io/docs/api/

I have installed this plugin https://github.com/VisualComposer/vcwb-demo-element-example-plugin. But when I am trying to add any new attribute into setting.json it not reflect in the UI.

Comment: You need to compile element any time when you change js or settings.

Comment: To compile: npm install && npm run build-production // Builds the minified build

Comment: Yes, I have add one new attribute from https://visualcomposer.io/docs/api/element-attributes/ ( checkbox attribute ) and I compile using npm build-production it was completed but in the wordpress I don't see any checkbox attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this attribute's key to the object - 'editFormTab1'. For example, there is an attribute - 'metaCustomId' and it has been added to the list in object - 'editFormTab1'.